# Printing a specific output from a list using for or while loop

Tags: python

What would be the best way to get the out put below form the list above it:

```
numbers = [1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Exepected output:

```
1 
1 2 
1 2 3 
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4 5
```

I tried the following but could not get the required output:

```
print("\nUsing for Loop")

for a in numbers:
    if a <= 5:
        print(a)

print("\nUsing While loop with list")

i=0
while True:
    i = i + 1
    if i == 5:
        break
    print(i)
```

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't meant to just give you code. We expect you to make an honest effort then ask a specific question about an error you have.

Comment: I tried the following: but could not get the required output:

Comment: print("\nUsing for Loop")

for a in numbers:
    if a <= 5:

        print(a)

print("\nUsing While loop with list")

i=0
while True:
    i = i + 1
    if i == 5:
        break
    print(i)

Answer (score 1):

You need to go through the list n times using slices to display the result

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
for i in range(len(numbers)):
    print(' '.join(map(str, numbers[:i+1])))
```